# java でフリーのプロファイラはありますか

Tags: java

java を、 spring-boot + intellij で開発していたところ、 Out of Heap エラーが発生しました。

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

プロファイラで原因を追究しようと思うのですが、フリーで使えるものはありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse(STS)を使っているのであれば、[MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)がいいと思いますが、IntelliJだと[VisualVM Launcher](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7115-visualvm-launcher)とか[JVM Debugger Memory View](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/jvm-debugger-memory-view-for-intellij-idea/)でしょうか。